# When we boil water, does the generated steam remain at the same temperature of boiling point until all water is boiled?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase

Suppose we are boiling water in such conditions so that the boiling point of water be $\pu{100 ^\circ C}$.

- Does the generated steam have the same temperature of 100 C until all water is boiled?
- And only after complete boiling does the temperature of steam start to rise?
- Does it make a difference if we are boiling with a lid on or not?
- Does only water have a temperature of 100 C and the temperature of
  steam increases even if all water is not boiled?
- In slightly  technical terms, is the heat provided to boil the water used only in changing the phase of water or is it also used in raising the temperature of the vapor formed?
- If the temperature of steam does remain constant until all water is boiled the question arises why, why does it remain constant?
- What is stopping the heat to not raise its temperature?
- What forces it to be only used do drive phase change?

Comment: Please read this webpage and re-formulate your question: http://www.sites.hps.cam.ac.uk/boiling/steampoint.htm

Comment: Also, the myth of the boiling point: http://www.sites.hps.cam.ac.uk/boiling/index.htm

Comment: Note that posted StackExchange(SE) questions containing merely just questions are usually closed on SE network. What particular things did not you understand while reviewing offline and online resources about this topic? Asking should be the last thing to do, but the questions seem to be the opposite. // The steam temperature can be at, below or above boiling point, depending on particular scenario and warming or cooling effects acting on the steam.

Comment: @AChem boiling is surprisingly very complicated. I could not understand the first linked page so I can not re-formulate the question,

Comment: @Osmium, As you can see, boiling process is indeed very complicated. Don't rely on  and digest web "answers" without thinking until and unless someone comes up with solid data and experimental measurements.

Comment: As the heating device has routinly surface $\pu{t \gt 100 ^\circ C}$, steam can have easily $\pu{t \gt 100 ^\circ C}$ as well. OTOH, if the surface is at steam section colder, or if is being mixed with air, steam can have easily $\pu{t \lt 100 ^\circ C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Steam (actually, water vapor) above a rapidly boiling can be *hotter* than the *average* temperature of the liquid because the situation is *not* in equilibrium.

Macroscopically, consider that in [nucleate boiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleate_boiling) the greater part of water in the container is *not* boiling; only in certain parts of the vessel has the water been superheated, and then flashes into vapor. "When the temperature difference is [sufficient], isolated bubbles form at nucleation sites and separate from the surface... [at a greater temperature difference] the vapor escapes as jets or columns which subsequently merge into slugs of vapor."

Those regions that formed bubbles were *above* the boiling point of water. Though the temperature of the bubble drops due to rapid expansion, it must still be **above 100 °C** or it would condense before reaching the surface (That oscillation of bubbles forming and collapsing can be observed at an incipient boil , i.e., [liquid entrainment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1yZwRcQSZw) stage of boiling.). Therefore, the vapor immediately released from the bubble can be hotter than the body of the liquid, which can be verified by putting a thermometer in the spout of a steaming kettle and in the liquid.

On a microscopic level, consider the fastest moving particles, i.e, the hottest, are the ones that escape. Of course, that is on *average*, since there can be areas in the liquid that are [superheated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superheating) and have not yet boiled.

Note, though, that in film boiling, the [Leidenfrost effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_boiling) maintains a layer of exceedingly hot **water vapor** against the surface of the container, *below* the level of the water! Of course, that is *not* liquid water, but it is below the surface of the water... so the answer to your question depends on the rate of boiling and where in the container you measure the temperature.

Comment: The key question before we speculate too much is where do we measure the temperature. A thermometer dipped in boiling water will read 100 Celcius under ordinary conditions. Where do measure the steam temperature? Right above the water, 12 inches away ? Let us think experimentally.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the nonequilibrium factors described well by DeMi8she Pippik, we may also consider the behavior when the water is not pure. Assuming we have set up nucle-ation sites and other factors so that the temperature no longer differs measurably from equilibrium, that equilibrium temperature will, in most practical cases, tend to rise as boiling proceeds and the composition of the liquid inevitably changes.

- With nonvolatile solutes, the frugality and therefore vapor pressure of the water will drop with the composition shifting to more solute. In the case of sugar solutions in water, this effect should be familiar to anyone who cooks candies or jams.
- With volatile solutes such as ethanol, the boiling starts off with predominantly the volatile solute at lower than the boiling point os the water alone, and the temperature rises as the liquid composition shifts towards more of the less volatile water component. Here the manufacturing of distilled liquor comes to mind.

Comment: I think the OP assumes standard, normal, usual and expected behavior of boiling water and wants to focus on behavior and properties of steam/vapor during the boiling process at various scenarios.

Comment: I think you meant "nucleation sites" rather than "nucleotide sites"? Nucleotides are biochemical compounds.

Comment: @andrew the largest number used in mathematics is not Skewes' number of Graham's number, but the number of times I have been burned by Autocorrect. I'm sure of it! Now to defeat it, I added a hyphen.